# How do region based services with a single backing database work to improve redundancy or load balancing?

Tags: load-balancing, redundancy

I've used services where there are multiple application servers spread out throughout US, at least I have to assume because I could explicitly use urls like `EastUS.email.Com` or `WestUS.email.Com` or `Euro.email.com` (as opposed to just `email.com`. I understand having multiple application servers to spread out the load, but what I don't understand is how I can apparently use any of the above urls to access the same email address and get up to date information -- This makes it seem like all three app pools connect to the same database -- If we only have one database, how does having multiple application servers help with load balancing and/or redundancy?

Comment: Databases can be replicated to many servers for both redundancy and geographic location.

Comment: @ceejayoz So in the event of three app servers, each having it's own database, would App server A stay in real time sync with DB's B, and C?

Comment: Maybe. Depends how you set it up. There are many different ways such a system could work behind the scenes.